# XeLaTeX with hyperref, import and standalone

Tags: xetex, hyperref, standalone, import

```
Package stringenc Error: Conversion to encoding `ascii-print' (stringenc) is not supported.
```

How can I avoid the above error when typesetting the parent file of the two below with XeLaTeX?

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{import}%
\usepackage[sort]{standalone}%


\begin{document}%

\subimport*{tex/section/}{Child}%

\end{document}%
```

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{hyperref}%


\begin{document}%

\section{Section}%

\end{document}%
```

The first file, the parent, is in a folder "MWE"; the second, the child, is in a folder "section", which is within "tex", which is within "MWE".

The error occurs when I run XeLaTeX a second time, after which output is produced, but only when I ignore errors, which impedes my finding more problematic errors.

Answer (score 2):

`\subimport*{tex/section/}{Child}%` removes TEXINPUTS from the search path and so your child document can no longer find files from the texmf tree in the document body.

Use the unstarred version instead:

```
 \subimport{tex/section/}{Child}%
```